# Using Methods in Serverside ControlIDs

Tags: asp.net, controls, server-side

i got the following code on my ASP-Site

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repFoo">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnfoo" Visible='<%#!String.IsNullOrEmpty("FOOValue")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

how is the correct syntax for the String.IsNullOrEmpty method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways :

declare function in your cs file that get the value and make your checks on it:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnfoo" Visible='<%# CheckNull(Eval("FOOValue")) %>' />

public bool CheckNull(object value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? fale : true;
}
```

OR use the function `IsNullOrEmpty` inline :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnfoo" Visible='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("FOOValue").ToString()) ? false : true %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

create a c# method--->

```
public string CheckIfNull(object myValue)
{
  if (myValue == null)
  {
     return "0 value";
  }

  return myValue.ToString();
}
```

.aspx--->

```
... Visible = <%# CheckIfNull(Eval("FOOValue")) %> ...
```

Comment: Visible expects a boolean Value, not a string but your way works